# Termination resistor in RTD analog front end

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog

First of all sorry for my English, it is not my first language and sometimes I cannot make myself completely clear.

I am in a project in which I would like to use RTD in order to measure temperature in several points, as usual, when I have to do an analog design I try to find some application note to get ideas.

In this case I have found an application note from TI (TIDU575–December 2014) which I have found very interesting, but I am struggling to understand why they are using 247R resistors at the end of the analog stage, after the filter and just before the ADC.
It remainds me of the termination resistor that are usually used for impedance matching in transmission lines to avoid wave reflections, but I dont get it in this case, I hava also consulted the articles in the documentation section and neither of them use this resistor.

I have also consulted the datasheet of the ADC (ADS1248) but I cannot find any reference to that.

All the opinions and advices are more than welcome, thank you in advance

The circuit I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any 247\$\Omega\$ resistors. The 249\$\Omega\$ resistors are not in the position you describe and are part of the filters.

Comment: Hardware debugging and test points.

Comment: @jay could you please describe it a little more

Comment: @ejht Sorry, I could not think of anything else but the circuit was taken from another design (by the datasheet author), including that red X. So, only purpose for 249 ohms are probing points to find during troubleshooting. One of my hardware engineers puts 33 ohm (not impedance thing) everywhere and masses up the board. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess 249Ω resistors using for low pass filter. You can look ***10.2.1.2.7 Input and Reference Low-Pass Filters*** section on ADS1248 datasheet.

Comment: ssThank you for the answer, but I dont see the filter there, I mean, I see the differential filter formed by the 4.12k resistors and 0.047uF and 4700pF capacitor, as there are described in the section commented, but the 247R does not appear in the datasheet.

Comment: I don't see any 247R on sharing image or TIDU575–December 2014 application note. If you talking about 249R in my opinion part of RC t filter. 4700p using for common mode filter and 0.047uf using for differential filter.